# Angular2 rxjs data async

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I make this template for display computed something.

compute function is getPredictedRate().

```
  <div class="ranking-list-container panel panel-default" *ngIf="isTasteGameRanking">
    <ul class="ranking-list list-group">
      <li class="ranking-element list-group-item row" *ngFor="let gameRate of gameRates | slice:0:10; let i = index;">
        <div class="index col-xs-1"> {{ i + 1 }} </div>
        <div class="game-title col-xs-10"><a (click)="moveToGameDetailPage(gameRate.gr_title)" > {{ gameRate.gr_title }} </a></div>
        <div class="game-rate col-xs-1" > {{ getPredictedRate(gamRate.gr_title) }} </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This is getPredictedRate()

```
 public getPredictedRate( targetGame:string ) {
    this.currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
    let num = 5;
    this.gameService.getGameByTitle( targetGame ).subscribe(
      game => {
        this.game = game;
        this.userService.getCompareUsersByTargetUserId( this.currentUser.id, num ).subscribe(
          compareUsers => {
            this.users = compareUsers;
            let result = this.predictedGameRateService.computePredictedGameRate( this.game, this.currentUser, this.users );
            console.log( result );
          }
        );
      }
    );
  }
```

If i call this function on template. this function was called over and over and over again.

What i miss in this code? Please Help me. I can't sleep two days. Because of this problem...

Comment: I think the template function can indeed be called very often, especially if Angular believe something might have changed. What I usually like to do is to calculate the value in a separate function, store the result in a variable and then let the template refer to the getter of that variable. That way your template will only do simple retrieval, while your computations are only executed when necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template re-evaluates the expression repeatedly. One solution could be to simply change it to:

```
    <div class="game-rate col-xs-1" >{{result}}</div>
```

Comment: you maen i make one private variable?

Comment: and i have additional question. i can't reach this.userService.getCompareUsersByTargetUserId() and this.predictedGameRateService.computePredictedGameRate(). why i can't reach them

Comment: Yes, make a component variable. Where are the unreachable variables defined?

Comment: i can't execute the functions not variables

Comment: You mean it never reaches the code? If it is, it is because it is a cold observable. Add `subscribe()` at the end.

Comment: Btw, you `getPredictedRate` does not return any value

Comment: But in general, something about the code seems complex and not clear. Use `map` and `switchMap` to transform the results in a sequence.